# Transaction is inconsistent. Reason: tails are not consistent

Tags: iota-network, javascript, promote

i'm trying to promote a transaction by using the following code

```
const spamTransfer = [{address: '9'.repeat(81), value: 0, message: '', tag: ''}]
iota.promoteTransaction(hash, 10, 9, spamTransfer, {interrupt: false, delay: 0});
```

but i receive this error

> Transaction is inconsistent. Reason: tails are not consistent (would
>   lead to inconsistent ledger state or below max depth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if the transaction is promotable before trying to promote it. For that transaction, `isPromotable` will return `false`, since it approves one or more transactions that are inconsistent (would be doublespends or reattaches of already confirmed transactions). When you try to promote it, chances are high that the promotion transaction will pick a milestone as second tip which already confirms the "other" transaction. As a result, your new transaction would not be confirmable either and therefore is rejected by the network.

If that happens, you will have to **reattach** the transaction instead. After reattaching, try to promote the **new** transaction, not the old one.